# mysql 4.x -> 5.x upgrade problem

Tags: mysql

im upgrading from mysql 4.x to 5 version.

in my php source i have following source  which working well on mysql 4.x version.

but if on mysql 5.x version, it not working.

i think following part of my php source some suspect which cause some problem.

if anyone help me much appreate

```
  <? 
    include('_connect_site_01.php');
    $DB = new MySQL;
    $DB->DBconnect();

    if(!$_GET[partner]) $_GET[partner] = "root";
    if(!$_GET[spcode]) $_GET[spcode] = "health";
    $date  = date("Y-m-d");
    $Query = "SELECT date FROM partner_count WHERE partner='$_GET[partner]' AND date='$date'"; 
    $DB->ExecSql($Query); $row = $DB->Fetch();

    if($row[date] == NULL)
    {
        $Insert = "INSERT INTO partner_count (id,partner, date, hit) VALUES('','$_GET[partner]','$date','1')";
        $DB->ExecSql($Insert);
    }
    else
    {
        $Update = "UPDATE partner_count SET hit= hit+1 WHERE partner='$_GET[partner]'";
        $DB->ExecSql($Update);
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: what does "it not working" mean? what actually is not working?

Comment: also - turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and make your script works without any warnings and notices.

Comment: im sorry i was't explain what is my serious problem! my problem is im using euckr korea language..but after upgraded mysql 5.x version. character was broken so it looks like '????'. i think i heard date function in mysql 5.x was changed compare with mysql 4.x . but don't know exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set colation and charset after you connect

```
SET NAMES koi8r;
SET CHARACTER SET koi8r;
SET collation_connection = koi8r_general_ci;
```

so after $DB->DBconnect(); you should run:

```
$DB->ExecSql("SET NAMES koi8r;");
$DB->ExecSql("SET CHARACTER SET koi8r;");
$DB->ExecSql("SET collation_connection = koi8r_general_ci;");
```

Comment: this code is awfully redundant. actually only first query is enough

Comment: i was attached full source following pastebin site http://pastebin.com/3Sg7SyWV    and also added $DB->ExecSql("SET NAMES koi8r;");
$DB->ExecSql("SET CHARACTER SET koi8r;");
$DB->ExecSql("SET collation_connection = koi8r_general_ci;");
but it can't send form data to other page.

Answer (score 0):

@cichy's answer is not clear. For mysql >=5.0 you **should** use [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset) and not the queries that he said.

Also, the data could be broken when you migrated to new mysql. You have not described how that migration was performed, so the root issue can be much more complex than just proper usage of `mysql_set_charset()`.

Comment: This only applies if the OP is using the mysql_*() function family (he doesn't say).

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: then he should use the function that is total synonym for `mysql_set_charset()` in his client library. Other implementations are ideologically wrong and can be vulnerable.